# Sitecore Commerce Authoring instance and Sitecore XP do not communicate well

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I have a problem with my Sitecore Commerce instance which I moved from another server where in works by copying wwwroot folders, databases and certificates on top of fresh SC Commerce install and editing the configs. The site itself works, but all commerce-related part of it does not. Commerce Engine starts successfully (I see an event about that in Event Viewer). This is what I see in the Sitecore Commerce Authoring logs:

```
00027 13:04:19 ERROR SitecoreConnectionManager.Error: Message=A task was canceled.|Trace= 
<....>  
00035 13:05:59 ERROR Management.block.getitemsbypath: Sitecore Item Service Get item failed, Item /sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Commerce Engine Settings/Commerce Terms/BusinessTools/ViewPropertyNames not found.
```

The item is actually present in content tree (both master and web) so it looks like it has trouble connecting to XP instance. There are no related errors in event viewer.

This is an error from XP logs:

```
8084 13:02:55 INFO  Commerce.Connector - Adding HttpClient BaseAddress: https://commerceauthoring.myproject.local/commerceops/, Language: en
8084 13:08:15 ERROR Commerce.Connector - Request URL: GetCatalogMappings(environmentName='') - Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

I have confirmed the following:

- `https://commerceauthoring.myproject.local` is a correct link which matches the binding in IIS
- bizfx, commerce authing and xp links are correct in `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config`, `\wwwroot\config.json` etc
- Certificate thumbprint in `CommerceAuthoring_QA\wwwroot\config.json` matches thumbprint `\App_Config\Include\Y.Commerce.Engine\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config` and it is matching the Commerce & Identity certificate in the store. This certificate is valid.
- SQL credentials are correct in the config files for commerce authoring
- gave to 'Everyone' all permissions for the certificates

I would appreciate if someone has advice on what else I could try/check. Maybe something regarding permissions/users under which the services are run? Thank you!

Comment: Did you bootstrap? is this working - https://commerceauthoring.myproject.local

Comment: Take a look at your PlugIn.Content.PolicySet-1.0.0.json and make sure Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionPolicy looks correct.
If you make any changes to the policy you need to bootstrap your commerce engine again.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal I actually moved the whole content etc from a working instance. Do I still need to bootstrap in this case?

Comment: yes, give it a try, also as @YassineAlahyane mentioned above, double check the entries in those configs

Comment: @GauravAgarwal thank you - I was able to get a hopefully more detailed error when trying to bootstrap. It's:  Error: write EPROTO 2586967656:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242 (if I try in Postman) and error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number in curl.

Comment: are you able to access url https://commerceauthoring.myproject.local/? it should show 404 on browser. and which version of SC?